# How to sort List<Map<String, String>>

Tags: salesforce

I've found a lot of information on how to sort a List, but none on how to sort a List>. Specifically I have a map of key values like:

```
"Name": "John",
"Savings": 300
```

I have a list of a bunch of objects like this and need to sort on "Savings". Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into the Comparable interface? You will need to wrap the Map<String,String> inside a new class that has a comparable() method in order to make it sortable. More info here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm

```
public class MapWrapper implements Comparable {

    public Map<String,String> record;

    public MapWrapper(Map<String,String> record) {
        this.record = record;
    }

    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        MapWrapper compareToMap = (MapWrapper)compareTo;
        if (record.get('Savings') == compareToMap.record.get('Savings')) return 0;
        if (record.get('Savings') > compareToMap.record.get('Savings')) return 1;
        return -1;        
    }
}
```

Your list will contain MapWrapper objects instead of Map<String,String>. You can then sort it using List.sort():

```
List<MapWrapper> myList = new MapWrapper[]{};
myList.add(new MapWrapper(new Map<String,String>{'Name'=>'John','Savings'=>'300'}));
myList.add(new MapWrapper(new Map<String,String>{'Name'=>'David','Savings'=>'100'}));

System.debug(myList); //Unsorted
myList.sort();
System.debug(myList); //Sorted
```

If you need to keep your structure as a `List<Map<String,String>>` without the wrapper, you can still do it but you will need to implement the sort algorithm yourself. The easiest way to do it is using bubble sort.